# Multiline string in swift and swift UI using binding object

Tags: swift, string, swiftui

I'm creating a custom banner or error view that shows as in attached image.
Below code is my view:

```
struct BannerModifier: ViewModifier {
@Binding var data: NotificationBannerData
@Binding var show: Bool

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ZStack {
        content
        if show {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        Text(data.title)
                            .bold()
                        HStack {
                            Image(data.iconName)
                            Text(data.detail)
                                .modifier(LinkText13Modifier())
                        }.padding(.bottom, 10)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(12)
                .background(data.type.tintColor)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .animation(.easeInOut)
            .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    self.show = false
                }
            }.onAppear(perform: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.show = false
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

}

Below is my preview:

```
struct Banner_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    let obj = Binding<NotificationBannerData>(get: { NotificationBannerData(title: "Title", detail: """
Detailed message that has to be displayed
when we have multiple lines to be displayed in \
the banner
""", type: .error, iconName: "icon_red") }, set: { _ in })
    
    let showVal = Binding<Bool> (get: { true }, set: { _ in })
    // Pass the binding object to the view
    HStack {
        Text("Show banner")
    }
    .banner(data: obj, show: showVal)
}
```

}

The problem is that when I've multiline string, it's not showing properly. It's showing as 3 lines and the expected is to have one string with wrapping.

[image]

Comment: What about a reproducible example? This works fine for me when I add a \ after the first row (after "displayed") but without using a Binding, which seems unnecessary anyway, and that secret modifier.

Comment: Don't use `Binding` unless you are actively using `set`. `Binding` is by definition a two-way connection

Comment: Just ```.lineLimit(1)``` to prevent multiline

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I will remove the binding. As I've to show it as an overlay when ever some error or warning is displayed, I'm using the modifier. Is there any better way to present it only when I've to show an error/warning?